# calling dependency service when app is destroyed

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, android-lifecycle

I have a background service which constantly access dependency service of Xamarin forms. So when the app is destroyed (killing/swiping) and background service tries to access this dependency service app gets crashed.

Crash says:

```
Cache.get_Connection ()
System.InvalidOperationException: You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to 
using it.
```

I have Xamarin.Forms.InIt() in mainactivity before calling LoadApplication().

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction):

> DependencyService allows apps to call into platform-specific functionality from shared code. This functionality enables Xamarin.Forms apps to do anything that a native app can do.

Since you are using an Android service, there are no necessary to call the dependency service. You could directly put the code into the service.

Comment: actually background service fetches the location and saves it to sqlite database. This is where the problem. As I need to get the sqlite connection using DependencyService it throws the crash.

Comment: @sai   When your app is destroyed all the resource include your activity and forms are released by the system. You could not access them anymore until the app is recreated. You could also get the sqlite connection in service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm